# Add YY.M date column to dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date

Say I have a dataframe with a single column A containing monthly observations from January 1980 to December 1990. How would I add a numeric column containing year and month in the format YY.M? It should look like this:

```
 A   Date
123  80.1
324  80.2
.     .
.     .
343  80.12
343  81.1
.     .
.     .
456  90.12
```

Comment: You just want it to run in sequence- one row per month, twelve rows per year?

Comment: Yes, as column A is ordered already and there are no missing observations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `seq` with `format` :

```
df$Date <- format(seq(as.Date('1980-01-01'), as.Date('1990-12-01'), 
                      by = "month"), "%y.%m")

#[1] "80.01" "80.02" "80.03" "80.04" "80.05"........
#[127] "90.07" "90.08" "90.09" "90.10" "90.11" "90.12"
```

Comment: While this works perfectly for the original question, I realized that plotting a line of A vs this way of having Date will not allow for even distribution of the dates across years in the X-axis, f.e.  for year 80 all its observations will be closer to year 80 than to 81. The dataframe 'airpass' from the 'faraway' package did it in a way that prevents this from happening, it looks like a sequence of 12 elements between 0 and 1 was looped for each year, but how?

Comment: @ForEverNewbie Probably, you should ask a new question for that.